# Last point hql search

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I need to make a simple query to chart some point (XY chart) within a date range.

**NB i use hibernate and HQL.**

My problem (as you can see in my wonderfull paint work!) is that i need to get the last point before my FROM date to draw the starting point of the chart (GREEN CIRCLE).

The query to get the last point take too much time.

Now i use this query :

from table where EVENTDATE < FROM ORDER DESC

and i took the first element

[image]

Can you help me resolving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is too slow , add a db index on EVENTDATE column of your table.

BTW you can rewrite your query to return only one row instead of loading all rows and taking one.

```
query = from table where EVENTDATE < FROM ORDER DESC
query.setMaxResults(1).
```

OR you can simply select max date

```
 query = select max(EVENTDATE) from table where EVENTDATE < FROM
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Setting maxresult i see that hiberate do the same query i do. I try in some minute with max!